# Como hacer un catalogo de productos

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

En esta imagen se muestra dropdown list, que contiene los productos existentes, para el caso no quiero usar esta lista, en cambio quiero un catálogo de productos que contenga todas las imágenes dentro del código aquí los diferentes productos, y al hacer clic en cualquier imagen, complete los detalles debajo de la lista desplegable. Esto se hace en ASP.net MVC.
¿CÓMO PUEDO HACER EL CATÁLOGO?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código que pinta el dropdownlist en la vista de ventas;**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-9 dropdown">
                            @Html.DropDownList("ListaProducto", ViewBag.ListaProducto as SelectList, "Seleccione un Producto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" name="btnproductos" id="btnproductos">Seleccionar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Este es el script para la función del botón de selección**

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnproductos").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Seleccionar",
                        data: { idProducto: $("#ListaProducto").val() },
                        success: function (mensaje) {
                            //alert(mensaje);
                            //$("#idproducto").val(mensaje.Nombre);
                            $(mensaje).each(function (index, item) {
                                //recibir datos json
                                $("#nombreproducto").val(item.Nombre),
                                $("#idproducto").val(item.IdProducto),
                                $("#precio").val(item.PrecioUnitario)
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

**Aquí los productos se cargan en el controlador de ventas;**

```
 public void cargarProductocmb()
                {
                    List<Producto> data = objProductoNeg.findAll();
                    SelectList lista = new SelectList(data, "idProducto", "nombre");
                    ViewBag.ListaProducto = lista;
                }
```

Comment: Quieres generar una tabla que contenga los datos de los productos con su imagen? o quieres hacer una lista desplegable que muestre la imagen ? disculpa, no entiendo bien que es lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Saludos, es una tabla que contenga las imagenes de los productos.

Comment: Hola @Fernando, quiero hacer una tabla que contenga las imagenes de los productos

Answer (score 0):

Espero te sea de ayuda, yo hago uso de DataTables, https://datatables.net/
en el cual yo puedo mostrar la imagen, la cual por buena practica te recomiendo guardar la ruta en un campo de la Base de datos.

En mi caso yo guardo el nombre del archivo de la siguiente manera:
en un folder de mi proyecto.

\imagenes\articulos\f17956b0-31ee-4d0e-90b1-2e0d2ba641da.png

Debes tener un cuerpo HTML de un tabla tal cual lo muestra en la documentación:

```
<table id="tblArticulos" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Clave</th>
                    <th>Nombre articulo</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>Fecha creacion</th>
                    <th>Imagen</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

Para después mandar a realizar la petición:

```
var dataTable;

$(document).ready(function () {
    cargarDatatable();
});


function cargarDatatable() {
    dataTable = $("#tblArticulos").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Administrador/Articulos/GetAll",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
            "data" : "tu dadat la colocas aqui"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id", "width": "5%" },
            { "data": "nombre_articulo", "width": "25%" },
            { "data": "categoria.nombreCategoria", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "fechaCreacion", "width": "15%" },
            {
                "data": "urlImagen",
                "render": function (imagen) {
                    return `<img src="../${imagen}" width="100%">`
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="text-center">
                            <a href='/Administrador/Articulos/Edit/${data}' class='btn btn-success text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:100px;'>
                            <i class='fas fa-edit'></i> Editar
                            </a>
                            &nbsp;
                            <a onclick=Delete("/Administrador/Articulos/Delete/${data}") class='btn btn-danger text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:100px;'>
                            <i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i> Borrar
                            </a>
                            `;
                }, "width": "30%"
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        "width": "100%"
    });
}
```

Ya con eso puedo generar el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sea de ayuda y que sea lo que necesites.

Comment: Gracias fernando, gracias a tu ayuda he podido encaminar a lo que quero hacer, ahora bien ya tengo un foreach y dento de el tengo definida una card de bootstrap, la pregunta es como le pasaria la ruta de la imagen que tengo guardada en sql ?

Comment: Este es el card: div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="@Url.Action("") " alt="Mi Imagen">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h4 class="card-title">Titulo de la tarjeta</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text">Texto de ejemplo</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Ir a …</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

Comment: y aqui busco todos los productos:   {
            List<Producto> data = objProductoNeg.findAll();
            SelectList lista = new SelectList(data, "idProducto", "nombre","imagenproduct");

            ViewBag.ListaProducto = lista;
        }

Comment: Suponiendo que la imagen ya la tienes almacenada en un folder o bien guardas la ruta completa lo unico que deberias hacer es lo siguiente:

Comment: Si guardar toda la ruta completa: <img src="@item.RutaFolderImagen"> por ejemplo, claro ese ítem haz referencia al campo que traes de tu modelo

Comment: Si unicamente guardar el nombre del archivo, y sabes en que carpeta la estas almacenando lo que deberias realizar es lo siguiente <img src="~/Images/@item.nombreImagen">